# How to force emacs to use \n instead of \r\n

Tags: emacs, shell, newline

I have to use windows to write some shell scripts.  I decided to use emacs, but I get a weird error when running the script:

`/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Correct me if I'm wrong, but that looks like the shebang ends in \r\n instead of just \n.  How can I tell emacs to only write \n?  I'm in Shell-script major mode.  It's quite surprising this isn't fixed by default.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, most *nix systems have the `dos2unix` utility installed to convert line-ends.

Comment: yeah, I'm using that for now.

Comment: How are you writing these scripts under Windows but running them using bash?

Comment: I use tramp's plink to get to the Linux box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jürgen mentioned, you need to use the `set-buffer-file-coding-system`. You can say

```
(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix)
```

and stick that into a function inside the `find-file-hook` so that it will set it for all the buffers you open. Alternatively, you can put it inside the `write-file-hook` list so that the file-coding-system is set properly before you dump the file to disk.

For a simpler way out, if you're using the GUI version of Emacs, you can click on the 3rd character in the modeline from the left. It's to toggle between eol formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
set-buffer-file-coding-system
```

(should be bound to a key-sequence) before saving the file.